# How to render two pagination in one view

Tags: laravel-5

I am currently coding on my laravel project and i have a
problem with my view with two different pagination.In the first pagination,
when i try to click (2-which is the next page),the second pagination is affected
even if it has different variable in line render.Anyone knows why it is 
happening?

My controller

```
public function viewlist($ship_id){
    $members = Member::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->paginate(3);
    $member = Member::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();
    $member_ids = [];
    foreach ($member as $mem) {
        array_push($member_ids, $mem->scholar_id);
    }
    $pendings = AddRequest::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->paginate(3);
    $pending = AddRequest::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();
    $pending_ids = [];
    foreach ($pending as $pend) {
        array_push($pending_ids, $pend->scholar_id);
    }

    $recommends = Recommend::where('ship_id', '=',$ship_id)->get();

    return view('pages.Organization.List-Of-Organization-Scholar',compact('ship','schol','pendings','members','count_member','recommends'))
;}
```

My View

```
@foreach($members as $member)
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="col-lg-12 well">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../{!! $member->Memscholar->scholar_image !!}" alt="" height="150" width="200">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class = "col-md-12">
        {!! $members->render() !!}
    </div>

@foreach($pendings as $pending)
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="col-lg-12 well">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../../{!! $pending->Pendscholar->scholar_image !!}" alt="" height="150" width="200">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
<div class = "col-md-12">
    {!! $pendings->render() !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

// Controller

// Change the page name before you make the paginator:

```
Paginator::setPageName('page_a');
$collection_A = ModelA::paginate(10);

Paginator::setPageName('page_b');
$collection_B = ModelB::paginate(10);
```

// View

// Do the same: change the page name before you print the links

```
Paginator::setPageName('page_a');
$collection_A->links();

Paginator::setPageName('page_b');
$collection_B->links();
```

// If you don't want to lose any page state while you navigate to another page, append to the links the current page from all collections:

```
Paginator::setPageName('page_a');
$collection_A->appends('page_b', Input::get('page_b',1))->links();

Paginator::setPageName('page_b');
$collection_B->appends('page_a', Input::get('page_a',1))->links();
```

Source:

http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/multiple-pagination-with-laravel-2-pagination-in-1-page

Comment: This is the error i've got " Class 'Paginator' not found ". Why is it looking for a paginator class?

Comment: I think you need to import it externally like: 
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
For more info on API: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html

Comment: but im using laravel 5.0 sir not laravel 5.4

Comment: The same class is available for both. Heres for Laravel 5.0:
https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html